# Oracle join operator

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

How to rewrite this:

```
select tab1.id, tab2.id, tab3.id 
from tab1, tab2, tab3 
where tab1.col1 = tab2.col1(+) and tab2.col2 = tab3.col2(+);
```

using OUTER JOIN syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select tab1.id, tab2.id, tab3.id 
from tab1
left outer join tab2 on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1
left outer join tab3 on tab2.col2 = tab3.col2;
```